# Number prototype to work with int and float

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I want to write a prototype to format numbers. 2 floating points and comma separator.

I wrote the prototype below.

I **works** with float.

```
    1.1.toBRLCurrency()
    // "1,10"
```

But it does **not work** with an int.

```
    1.toBRLCurrency()
    // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The funny thing i noticed is that both ( int and float ) return the type number.

```
    typeof 1.1
    // "number"

    typeof 1
    // "number"
```

I don't know what I'm missing.
Here's my code.

```js
Number.prototype.toBRLCurrency = function(){
    var options = {
        'minimumFractionDigits':2,
        'maximumFractionDigits': 2
    }
    return this.toLocaleString('pt-BR',options);
}

var n = 1.1;
console.log( n, typeof n ); 
console.log(1.1.toBRLCurrency());

n = 1;
console.log( n, typeof n ); 
//console.log(1.toBRLCurrency())
```

Comment: Numbers are primitives. You need to create a normal method.

Comment: `(1).toBRLCurrency()` — you have to deal with the fact that `.` is parsed as part of the number literal.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy !

Comment: Or just use `n.toBRLCurrency()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pointy!

**(1).toBRLCurrency()**

```js
Number.prototype.toBRLCurrency = function(){
    var options = {
        'minimumFractionDigits':2,
        'maximumFractionDigits': 2
    }
    return this.toLocaleString('pt-BR',options);
}

var n = 1.1;
console.log( n, typeof n ); 
console.log(1.1.toBRLCurrency());

n = 1;
console.log( n, typeof n ); 
console.log((1).toBRLCurrency())
```